# NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am getting `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference` at this line of code.

```
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
```

My code,

```
private List<QuizWrapper> returnParsedJsonObject(String result) {

    List<QuizWrapper> jsonObject = new ArrayList<QuizWrapper>();
    JSONObject resultObject = null;
    JSONArray jsonArray = null;
    QuizWrapper newItemObject = null;
    try {
        resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
        System.out.println("Testing the water " + resultObject.toString());
        jsonArray = resultObject.optJSONArray("quiz_questions");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = null;
        try {
            jsonChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = jsonChildNode.getInt("id");
            String question = jsonChildNode.getString("question");
            String answerOptions = jsonChildNode.getString("possible_answers");
            int correctAnswer = jsonChildNode.getInt("correct_answer");
            newItemObject = new QuizWrapper(id, question, answerOptions, correctAnswer);
            jsonObject.add(newItemObject);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

My logcat error,

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: androidquizapplication.inducesmile.com.itona, PID: 12093
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int org.json.JSONArray.length()' on a null object reference
      at androidquizapplication.inducesmile.com.itona.QuizActivity.returnParsedJsonObject(QuizActivity.java:246)
      at androidquizapplication.inducesmile.com.itona.QuizActivity.access$1400(QuizActivity.java:37)
      at androidquizapplication.inducesmile.com.itona.QuizActivity$AsyncJsonObject.onPostExecute(QuizActivity.java:201)
      at androidquizapplication.inducesmile.com.itona.QuizActivity$AsyncJsonObject.onPostExecute(QuizActivity.java:167)
```

your help will help me a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> problem is "resultObject.optJSONArray("quiz_questions")" this value is null.

```
List<QuizWrapper> jsonObject = new ArrayList<QuizWrapper>();
JSONObject resultObject = null;
JSONArray jsonArray = null;
QuizWrapper newItemObject = null;
try {
    resultObject = new JSONObject(result);
    System.out.println("Testing the water " + resultObject.toString());
    jsonArray = resultObject.optJSONArray("quiz_questions");
} 
catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
if (jsonArray != null) {     // check jsonArray is null?
    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonChildNode = null;
        try {
            jsonChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            int id = jsonChildNode.getInt("id");
            String question = jsonChildNode.getString("question");
            String answerOptions = jsonChildNode.getString("possible_answers");
            int correctAnswer = jsonChildNode.getInt("correct_answer");
            newItemObject = new QuizWrapper(id, question, answerOptions, correctAnswer);
            jsonObject.add(newItemObject);
        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return jsonObject;
}
```

Comment: sorry I'm so beginner, but the quiz_questions is my table and that table has a value. but still result null(empty). :(

Comment: you should checking your code, and find first null object.

Comment: Sir it already work on me. THANK YOU VERY MUCH! you save me from my headache

Comment: Im following a tutorial (android quiz application with json parse) then my one error is fixed i already have two error. thanks alot